# Nginx Deny specific file types in images folder

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx and I want to prevent access on html files inside my images folder.
I have tried

```
location /images/.*\.html {
        deny all;
}
```

but I still can access /images/test.html.

How can I prevent access to test.html ?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/808788/nginx-wildcard-regex-in-location-path - `location ~ ^/images/.*\.html$ {` or something similar should work.

Comment: That helped me to solve it. If you posted as an answer I will marked it as the solving answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `location` element accepts regex for pattern matching ([as described on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/808788/nginx-wildcard-regex-in-location-path)), but you'll have to tell it that it's a regex by adding `~` between the `location` key and the pattern itself:

```
location ~ ^/images/.*\.html$ {

}
```